# tt and ti characters are not getting copied correctly

Tags: xetex, unicode, overleaf

I have formatted my resume in Latex using overleaf but when I copy the paragraph to a word file certain characters are not getting copied correctly. For example

```
Fixed bugs in the fluer mobile applicaon
```

should be

```
Fixed bugs in the flutter mobile application
```

similiarly

```
counng
```

should be

```
counting
```

What I have noticed is that the letter tt and ti are not UTF-8 compatible and I was wondering if there's anything that I did wrong.

I tried including

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

in my main.tex file but it did not work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us (a) whether you use pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, or XeLaTeX, (b) which font package(s) you employ, and (c) how you compile the document -- direct to pdf or indirect via dvi.

Comment: Which font provides both `tt` and `ti` ligatures?

Comment: @Mico I am using a predefined template RahulWorld Resume on overleaf. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/rahulworld-resume/pxynfdjpdryc

It is XeLatex and uses Calibri Font. Also I am using the ctrl+Enter in overleaf to compile it and then download it.

Comment: This may or may not be related to the current topic, but here it goes: in Adobe PDF reader, if I copy say "https://..." and if it's in Italics, the pasted words are "h5ps://..." so it takes the italics tt and converts it to 5.
If it's not italics, eg, Attached, it becomes A"ached on copy-paste to a browser from the Adobe pdf reader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with xelatex in texlive 2019. Switching to texlive 2020 in overleaf should resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is an issue with ligatures. Have you tried loading glyphtounicode.tex? Together with `\pdfgentounicode=1` this should take care of the issue.

```
\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1
```

Alternatively try using `LuaLaTex` or `XeLaTex`.

Comment: The template that I am using is XeLaTeX. It is in overleaf. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/rahulworld-resume/pxynfdjpdryc 

I tried using 
```
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
```

but it gave an error that latex could not compile the file.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don’t have a publisher forcing you to keep using 8-bit fonts in 2020, one solution is to compile in LuaLaTeX and load `\usepackage{fontspec}`.  You might need to replace a font package you use with an equivalent `\setmainfont` command, and you can use any font you are able to in Word.

Alternatively, if you do want to stick with PDFTeX, you can try `\usepackage{mmap}`.  Also `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in PDFTeX if you aren’t already.  This should translate most of the symbols in your document to Unicode.